# JPA/Hibernate Persist cascades even if it shouldn't

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I got these 2 entities:

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
public class Book {
    @javax.persistence.EmbeddedId
    private BookPK id;

    private String title;

    @javax.persistence.ManyToOne(fetch = javax.persistence.FetchType.LAZY)
    @javax.persistence.JoinColumns({ 
            @javax.persistence.JoinColumn(name = "LNGCOD", referencedColumnName = "LNGCOD"),
            @javax.persistence.JoinColumn(name = "LIBCOD", referencedColumnName = "LIBCOD") })
    private Language language;
}

@javax.persistence.Entity
public class Language {
    @javax.persistence.EmbeddedId
    private LanguagePK id;

    private String name;
}
```

with composed PK's:

```
@Embeddable
public class BookPK implements Serializable {
    private Integer bookcod;
    private Integer libcod;
}

@Embeddable
public class LanguagePK implements Serializable {
    private Integer lngcod;
    private Integer libcod;
}
```

If I try to create a new Book and persist it, I get an exception telling me libcod is found twice in the insert statement ("Column 'libcod' specified twice"). But I can't use "insertable = false" when defining the JoinColumn ("Mixing insertable and non insertable columns in a property is not allowed").

Is there any way to define these objects + relationship so the columns are managed automatically by Hibernate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate and JPA automatically make persistent all the modifications made to persistent entities while they are attached to the session. That's the whole point of an ORM: you load a persistent object, modify it, and the new state is automatically persisted at the commit of the transaction, without any need to call persist, merge, save or any other method.

Note that calling `persist` on a persistent entities (except for its cascading side-effects) makes no sense. `persist` is to make a transient entity (i.e. a new one, not in the database yet, with no generated ID) persistent.

Comment: Nevermind. I set up my tests in a hurry and made some mistakes. The tests were supposed to run with detached objects. I ran into a new issue now, so please check the edited question. Thanks.

Comment: You have a really strange schema here: it would be impossible to change the language of a book without changing its primary key. I would use single-column surrogate keys. And if you can't, then I would have two seperate libcod columns: one for the book's primary key, and one for the language foreign key.

Comment: The problem is I can't change the database structure. I HAVE to work with this legacy DB so I am trying to find the most elegant way of describing and managing it via JPA. Of course I'd prefer to have simple id's for PK's and FK's, but ...

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one mutator for the libcod. Probably, what you should do is leave the libcod getter in the BookPK class, and in the Language class, use a joincolumn reference with a ref back to the libcod. It works fine for single embedded PK classes, but for multiple PK classes, you may have to play around.

So, in your Language class, you would have this.

```
    @javax.persistence.Entity public class Language {

    private LanguagePK id;
    private Integer    libcod;

    @javax.persistence.EmbeddedId @AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "lngcod", column = @Column(name = "LNGCOD", nullable = false)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "libcod", column = @Column(name = "LIBCOD", nullable = false)) })
    public LanguagePK getId() {
            return this.id;
    }
     public void setId(LanguagePK id) {
          this.id = id;
    }    


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)

       @JoinColumn(name = "LIBCOD", insertable = false , updatable = false)
         public Integer getLibcod() {
       return this.libcod;
         }
```